# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1,

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to use Azure Blob Storage, however I am getting the following error.

> System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'

I have viewed other solutions on Stackoverflow that suggest changing from "Any CPU" to "x64", Doing a clean then build, and making the app.config match the version in the packages.config. None of these things solve the problem.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and .NET Framework 4.7.2

The offending line of code is

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
```

Can anyone provide some insight on why this is happening?

Comment: maybe try a clean and rebuild at the solution level. It also be a bad dll reference in .csproj, or something was copy and pasted in csproj incorrectly for package reference.

Comment: @Dave, based on my test, I can run the code in the same environment successfully. Therefore, I suggest that you can create a new project for testing it.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT I gave that a try. It seemed to resolve the reference issues, but now I have a new problem. I'll start a new question for that. Thanks.